# Rails: to_set db storage for an array of integers

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I've been searching for an extensive explanation of Rails' operator `to_set`, without much success. It seems like one would be able to store an array of integers in `to_set`, such as user ids. Is it possible to store this in the database? If so, what is the proper way to include this in a migration?

I'm hoping it is possible to directly store a set of integers in a db using this operation. If not, I'm assuming the proper way to achieve this integer storage is to `serialize` a `string`/`text` field in the database, then call it back with `to_set` (or `to_i`?). I also came across a "`push`" operator that assists `to_set` in retrieving integers. If anybody could provide a detailed explanation of to_set and how to store an array of integers into a database field, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With MySQL you're stuck with `serialize` but I strongly recommend against it as sooner or later you'll want to look inside the array in a query and that's nasty if you use `serialize`; use a separate assoc table instead. As far `to_set` goes, that's patched into [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_set) by [`set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) from the standard Ruby library.

Comment: *Hypothetically*, if I was going to store a LOT of integers into a serialized text field, how would I call them back as ids of another table? And (for what you suggested) how would I connect those three tables in a model?

Comment: Why do you want to store a set in the db? Why not an extra table? Most of the time it is a pretty bad idea to store serialized data: You cannot easily query it, you cannot easily change it, it slows down everything, ...